Prepend text to mysqldump output at dump creation time
I am suffering from slow mysqldump/mariadb-dump.
I found that disabling autocommit, unique_checks and foreign_key_checks boost import performance.
I do that by prepending dump.sql with
SET autocommit=0;SET unique_checks=0;SET foreign_key_checks=0;

and by appending
COMMIT;SET unique_checks=1;SET foreign_key_checks=1;

to the end of it.
Append is trivial, but when prepending I need to make a compromise between time or space consumed.
Prepending with
sed -i '0,/^/s//SET autocommit=0;SET unique_checks=0;SET foreign_key_checks=0;/' dump.sql

can take a lot of time for large dumps, but it creates a single file.
cat <(echo "SET autocommit=0;SET unique_checks=0;SET foreign_key_checks=0;") dump.sql <(echo "COMMIT;SET unique_checks=1;SET foreign_key_checks=1;") > new-dump.sql"

Is fast, but it creates another dump file and is therefore using a lot of space (even though it is just temporary)
Is it possible to instruct mysqldump/maridb-dump to prepend and append a custom text to the dump when it is creating it?

Using echo before and after the mariadb-dump command and then redirecting the output into a file should work at least with bash:
(echo "SET autocommit=0;SET unique_checks=0;SET foreign_key_checks=0;" && \
 mariadb-dump <options...> && \
 echo "COMMIT;SET unique_checks=1;SET foreign_key_checks=1;") > dump.sql

This also works when you pipe the output to a remote server or another program like gzip.

Or one can use >> to append file instead of > (to overwrite)

I'd say you rarely want to use appending as the data then has to be first stored uncompressed on the disk. You might as well pipe the output directly into a program like gzip to compress it and then optionally send it directly to a remote server via something like socat.
